# Why am I getting the error 'Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.' in useNavigationBuilder.tsx?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

```
      if (route?.name) {
        routeNames.push(route.name);
      }
    } else {
      route = state.routes[state.index];
      routeNames.push(
        ...Object.keys(screens).filter((name) => route?.name === name)
      );
    }
```

I'm getting an error in a file I haven't touched while building my React Native app, and it's causing confusion

Comment: Can you share from which line the error comes from? Also, where and how have you defined your variables here?

Comment: If we mention only the redvhighlighted part, the following code is "routeNames.push(route.name);" ,"...Object.keys(screens).filter((name) => route?.name === name)"

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening during push you should double check your typings for routeNames.

What might be happening...
if your routeNames have an interface or type like:

```
ExampleType = { name:string, id:number}
```

then a .push({name, string}) will work.

However, you are using a spread operator (...). This can unintentionally push other attributes to your object which will give a never type mismatch.

for example, if I tried to push an obj with name, id, path etc into ExampleType, I will receive the same error because they do not exist within that object so the object does not allow it.